# Electron JS watch large set of files efficiently

Tags: javascript, electron, chokidar

I am creating an electron js application where I want to sync the files recursively in the directories that are configured by the user.

The following is currently implemented in the application

1. When the app boots, use chokidar to get the initial state of files and sync with the config.json using electron-store. This is to get the latest update of the file while the application is closed
2. Run a persistent watcher right after initial sync to get the `add`, `unlink` and `change` event and notify the user somehow.

The problem is with the first case. Since the user is linking so many files with multiple nesting the electron app lags until all the files are being processed.

What I want to know exactly is, "Efficient way to watch a really large amount of  files / directories"